# What is Undecidability and its practical application?

Tags: computation-theory

I have a vague understanding of undecidability. I get it that undecidability is that for a problem there exists no algorithm or the Turing machine will never halt. But I cant just visualize it. Can someone explain in a better way. and I don't get why we are learning about it and its applications. Can someone explain in this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental concept being explored here is decision problems. A [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem) is any problem that can be formulated as a yes/no (or true/false) question and expressed in a formal language, such as lambda calculus or the input to a Turing machine.

A problem is [*undecidable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) if there exists no algorithm that can give the right answer on every possible input. It might help to think about the converse of this: If we have some undecidable problem and Bob comes along and says he's got an algorithm that solves it (*decides* the problem), well then there's going to be at least one input that causes Bob's algorithm to give the wrong answer or loop infinitely.

The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is a decision problem - an excellent example of one that is undecidable. In fact, it was the first decision problem to be shown to be undecidable.

For the sake of keeping things concrete, let's say Alice would like to have a program for her Turing machine that can analyze any program and predict with perfect accuracy whether or not it will halt. Bob comes along with his program, which he calls P for "the Perfect Program!" He claims it'll do the job.

Skeptical, Alice takes P and starts writing her own program, which she calls Q (for Quixotic). Like P, Q takes any program as its input. When it gets its input, Q immediately calls P and asks it what the input program is going to do.

- If P says the input program is going to run forever, Q prints "Done!" and immediately halts.
- If P says the input program is going to halt, Q prints "Looping!" and then enters an infinite loop from which it will never return.

What happens if we run Q and give it its own source code as input (We run `Q(Q)`)?

- If P says Q will run forever, Q immediately prints "Done!" and halts, so it can't do that. It would be giving the wrong answer.
- If P says Q will halt, Q prints "Looping!" and then enters an infinite loop. So P would be giving the wrong answer here too.

So no matter what P does, it *can't* give the correct answer. Bob claimed it solved the halting problem (it *always* gives the right answer, on *every* input)! But doing so would produce a contradiction, as we see above. So, Bob can't be telling the truth about this program P of his. And in fact, it doesn't even matter what's actually in Bob's program. It could be simple, or it could be ridiculously complex. No matter how sophisticated or clever or elegant it is, it *can't* solve the problem. Not with 100% accuracy, as decision problems require. No program can. *That's* what undecidability means.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the "practical application" part of this question, developing compilers is a good example of how undecidability can be leveraged in real life.

Some compilers make every effort to identify bad behavior that will happen at runtime. For example, it would be pretty cool if your C compiler could always, 100% of the time tell you if the program you have written down is going to loop infinitely or have a segmentation fault, for example. But, it can't! If it could, the C compiler would be deciding an undecidable problem (the halting problem, in the case of infinite loops).

I'm not an expert in compilers, but I'd bet that having a pretty solid understanding of decidability is pretty important for researchers / engineers working on cutting edge compilers. Will you and I, as average Joes, have a practical application for decidability? Probably not. But it's still pretty cool!

Comment: Strictly speaking, you don't care what your C program might do if given infinite memory. With finite memory, it's a finite state machine and thus decidable (though deciding it in practice might be computationally intractable). I think it's the case for all undecidable problems that any practical application only cares for solutions within a finite bound. This would suggest that undecidability never has practical relevance, other than as a source for ideas when thinking about finite problems as infinite.

Comment: This is not true. A program is distinct from how much memory the computer that runs the program has. It is 100% mathematically impossible for you to even *devise* of an algorithm (never mind programming it in real life with finite hardware constraints -- impossible to just derive an abstract algorithm) that will return TRUE if and only if a program P does NOT contain an infinite loop for _any_ program P.

The **input sequence** is what matters and that has an **infinite** domain.

Comment: Yes, in theory. In practice not really. Whether this difference between theory and practice is actually important might depend on the application (you still can't write a compiler in practice that finds all the infinite loops you might care about) but programs running on actual computers never have infinite memory or can be arbitrarily long. Thus, what I was saying is that the undecidability analysis is dealing with an idealized (unrealistic) scenario. Not understanding how this differs from reality can lead to a lot of misconceptions about what undecidability means, especially "in practice".

Comment: For example, a lot of people think undecidability implies that it's impossible to prove any interesting property about a computer program (which is kind of true "in theory for infinite memory etc." according to Rice's theorem). However, in practice that is not true and you can prove things about programs. For example, people have "proven the correctness" of a certain C compiler, which is a huge program.

Comment: I see what you're saying from a high-level perspective re: differentiating theory and practice and that ignoring nuances between the two can lead you down bad paths, but I don't agree with some of the other stuff here.

Specifically, I do agree no program compiled by a compiler has infinite memory, but it actually *does* has arbitrarily large amounts of memory as far as the compiler is concerned. E.g. a C compiler has absolutely no insights about the size of the heap the program will eventually have access to. Thus the halting problem for C programs is in fact still undecidable.

Comment: I disagree with this assertion: "a lot of people think undecidability implies that it's impossible to prove any interesting property about a computer program". I doubt many people think this. Proving the correctness of a C compiler is a relatively simple problem. C has a formal language definition (its operational semantics), so the input domain (all *valid* C programs) is ridiculously constrained. Compare that to the domain of the halting problem (all valid programs + all inputs). Anyone that's seriously wrestling with undecidability and proving program properties will see the difference.

Comment: I've spoken with a lot(>10, which is a lot considering how often you get to discuss such topis with people who have heard of Rice's theorem) of people who interpreted Rice's theorem that way. I guess depending on seriousness, it's valid to assume "someone seriously wrestling with undecidability and proving program properties" can be expected to know pretty much everything about the topic that has ever been published. I don't know any such person and there might not be even a thousand of them worldwide for what I know.

Comment: Concerning "C programs undecidable", sure. But this is again not relevant in practice. If compiler developers were able to significantly improve the compiler if only they were allowed to assume no program will ever have more than 2^(10^1000000) bytes of memory, they would and then C programs would be decidable. The "practically interesting problem" is "how hard is it to reason about programs that have realistic amounts of memory". This question is very hard and maybe can be inspired from undecidability. In my personal subjective experience, proving things about useful programs is also hard.